# TFS 2010 - Build and Test Nightly

Tags: visual-studio, build, configure

I'm new on StackExchange and i'm a french guy so sorry for my english...

I search something to help me for continue integration on TFS web.
In fact, i want to build and make test during night because some of workers take the memory on the day...

I have some project to build and test during night and i want to see the result in the morning on the web interface of TFS...

I have already installed TFS 2010, build agent and test agent but i don't see anyone tutorial about this configuration...

If someone can help me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is configured in the build definition. If you search the internet for *TFS 2010 Build Definition* you should find a ton of information. Here is one such resource: [tfs-2010-the-new-build-definition-window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/01/19/tfs-2010-the-new-build-definition-window.aspx)

You specify when to build in the *Trigger* section:
[image]
You can specify tests to run in the *Process* section:
[image]

***EDIT*** If you are using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Thanks for the rapidity of your response, i'm going to check about TFS build definition...